# Can connect to AWS RDS through MySQL Workbench but not through python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql-python

I am working on a simple python script that stores passwords for various accounts in a database (similar to LastPass) and I am having trouble connecting to the AWS RDS instance that I set up. I made sure to configure the RDS instance so that it is public and accepts connections from any IP.

Here is the code that I use to connect to the AWS RDS instance:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

...

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="RDS Endpoint", port=####, user="username", passwd="password", db="passworddb")
crsr = conn.cursor()
```

When I run the script, I get the error: `_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Unknown database 'passworddb'` However, when I attempt to connect to the database through MySQL Workbench using the same endpoint, username, password, and database name, it connects just fine, leading me to believe that it is either something wrong with the way I am connecting through my python script or something on Amazon's end.

If the way I am connecting to the RDS instance in my script is incorrect or impractical it would be greatly appreciated if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Comment: try connecting from the same server using a ssh tunnel, or the `mysql` client on the same server as the code.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen this, but it's possible you're passing the arguments to the connect method in the wrong order, and not using the correct names. For example, `passwd` may need to be `password` and `db` may need to be `database`... see here. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html